# how to insert a list of dicts to sqlalchemy flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionaries like that:

```
[{'cx_agent': 'samir', 'supervisor': 'karim', 'convo_link': 'test', 'date_of_conversation': '11/01/2001', 'quality_agent': ''}, {'cx_agent': 'farah', 'supervisor': 'kazem', 'convo_link': 'test', 'date_of_conversation': '10/01/2002', 'quality_agent': ''}, {'cx_agent': 'captain', 'supervisor': 'ahmed', 'convo_link': 'helmy', 'date_of_conversation': '10/01/2003', 'quality_agent': ''}]
```

I want to add it to this database

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
#Initialize Database
db=SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class Auditing(db.Model):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cx_agent: Mapped[str]= mapped_column(String,nullable=False)
    supervisor: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String,nullable=False)
    convo_link: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String,nullable=False)
    quality_agent: Mapped[str]=mapped_column(String,nullable=True)
    date_of_conversation: Mapped[Date]= mapped_column(Date,nullable=False)
```

I was trying using this code but it didn't work

```
import gspread
import pandas as db
sa= gspread.service_account(filename="Keys.json")
sh= sa.open("Quality Auditing Queue")
wks=sh.worksheet("Queue")
queue= wks.get_all_records()
stmt=insert(Auditing).values(queue)
Session.bulk_insert_mappings(Auditing,queue)
```

queue = the dict

Comment: "it didn't work" - please [edit] the question to explain exactly how it didn't work.  Did you call `session.commit()` to commit the data to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it by making for loop in the queue and adding the result in another dictionary then call to add and commit

```
for dict in queue:
    new_dict = Auditing(id=dict["id"],cx_agent=dict['cx_agent'] ,supervisor=dict["supervisor"],convo_link=dict['convo_link'],date_of_conversation=dict['date_of_conversation'],quality_agent=dict['quality_agent'])
    db.session.add(new_dict)
    db.session.commit()
return redirect(url_for('add_chats'))
```